# How many different languages are spoken?

Tags: dialogue, everything-everywhere-all-at-once

[Everything Everywhere All At Once](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6710474/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) is a fairly insane experience in many ways.

There is an enormous and sometimes very rapid flow of images, for example. But, less remarked, there is also a wide variety of languages being spoken. (English cinema releases have a lot of subtitles.)

The lead characters switch between Chinese and English, sometimes mid sentence. But *which* Chinese languages? I've heard they use both Mandarin and Cantonese in different contexts. I suspect there are other languages as well, including some that might be made up (there is a subtitled scene where Michelle Yeoh seems to be using a language that involves only whistling).

So what have I missed? How many distinct languages are spoken by the characters in the movie (and does whatever rocks speak count?)? Is there any rationale for why they switch?

Answer (score 6):

1. English
2. Mandarin
3. Cantonese

There was also

4. Bird calls/Bird tweets
5. Dialogue between rocks

Source: [Script](https://nofilmschool.com/sites/default/files/eeaao_script.pdf)

---

I speak both Mandarin and Cantonese and here are some of my observations/speculations:

Both Evelyn (Michelle Yeoh) and Waymond (Ke Huy Quan) use both Mandarin and Cantonese (though mainly Mandarin and only a little Cantonese). Both speak Mandarin with "non-standard" (non-Northern/Beijing) accents.

Evelyn's Cantonese is more close to "standard Hong Kong"; Waymond's much less so.

Gong Gong speaks only Cantonese (though Alpha Gong Gong also speaks English).

Joy speaks Mandarin and not Cantonese. She speaks Mandarin with a distinctly "standard" accent--so one possibility is that she learnt Mandarin in school in the US and didn't pick up either of her parents' Mandarin accents.

I'm pretty sure the flashback/multiverse scenes are to Hong Kong based on these clues: (1) When Evelyn is born, the doctor speaks to Gong Gong in Cantonese; (2) There was a shot with a Hong Kong taxi; (3) Some shots had traditional (rather than simplified) Chinese characters; (4) The movie-within-movie credits were in the style of 1970s-90s Hong Kong cinema.

That Evelyn and Waymond speak both Mandarin and Cantonese to each other (and in non-standard accents) suggests they do not share the same strongest (or "native") language.

So, one possibility is that Waymond is not a native Cantonese speaker; was from some other part of China or the world, moved to Hong Kong, where he learnt Cantonese and also met Evelyn.

---

A few more notes:

Mandarin and Cantonese are completely distinct languages (as different as English from say German).

Michelle Yeoh grew up speaking English and Cantonese (source: Financial Times interview, [2023](https://www.ft.com/content/02a7a32a-3e6a-421a-982c-feeb29c445a4)). She only learnt Mandarin when preparing to film Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon ([source](http://michelleyeoh.info/Bio/qa.html)).

Ke Huy Quan is Chinese-Vietnamese, but I'm not sure when/how he learnt Mandarin and Cantonese and whether he would consider one of these two his stronger or "more native" language.